# Using Jarbundler with ant

Tags: java, ant

Im trying to use a jarbundler to create a .app file with ant. But I'm getting the following error:

> taskdef class net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler cannot be found 
>   using the classloader
>   AntClassLoader[/Users/Ida/NetBeansProjects/supernova/build/classes/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar]

My build.xml looks like this:

```
 <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="dist/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <copy todir="build/classes">
            <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="dist">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes/lib"/>
        <copy flatten="true" todir="build/classes/lib" includeemptydirs="false">
            <fileset dir="dist/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/SuperNova.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <fileset dir="dist/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <mkdir dir="build/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="build/jar/SuperNova.jar" basedir="build/classes">
            <fileset dir="dist/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="build/jar/SuperNova.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>



    <target name='package-app'>
        <taskdef name="jarbundler" classname="net.sourceforge.jarbundler.JarBundler">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="build/classes/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </taskdef>
        <jarbundler dir="dist" name="SuperNova" 
            mainclass="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp"
            jar="build/jar/SuperNova.jar"/>
    </target>
```

Does anybody now why I'm getting this error and how I should solve it?

**EDIT**

Thanks for your help. I can now build the .app file but when I'm trying to run it I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp

My target now looks like this:

```
<target name='package-app'>
        <taskdef name="jarbundler" classpath="build/classes/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar" 
        classname="com.ultramixer.jarbundler.JarBundler"/>

        <jarbundler dir="dist" name="SuperNova" 
            jar="build/jar/SuperNova.jar"
            mainclass="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp"
            icon="SuperNova copy.icns"
            stubfile="universalJavaApplicationStub"
            useJavaXKey="true"
            jvmversion="1.7+"/>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the jar to take a look, and I think the issue is that your `classname` is wrong. The JarBundler class is located in `com.ultramixer.jarbundler.JarBundler`, so try this instead:

```
    <taskdef name="jarbundler" classname="com.ultramixer.jarbundler.JarBundler">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="build/classes/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
```

Also, since you're only loading a single library, there's no need use a nested classpath instead of `taskdef`'s `classpath` attribute, so you can simplify it somewhat:

```
    <taskdef
        name="jarbundler"
        classname="com.ultramixer.jarbundler.JarBundler"
        classpath="build/classes/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar"
    />
```

Comment: I edited my original post because I ran into a new problem.

Comment: It looks like a similar pathing issue in your project's jar, but without access to that jar file I can't say what the problem is exactly.

Comment: See answer below to the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the lib folder was not in the destination with the jar so I solved it by editing my hole build.xml file to only look like this:

```
<target name='package-app' depends='clean, jar'>
    <taskdef name="jarbundler" classpath="dist/lib/jarbundler-core-3.3.0.jar" 
    classname="com.ultramixer.jarbundler.JarBundler"/>

    <jarbundler dir="dist" name="SuperNova" 
        jar="dist/SuperNova.jar"
        mainclass="com.lumenradio.supernova.SuperNovaApp"
        icon="SuperNova copy.icns"
        stubfile="universalJavaApplicationStub"
        useJavaXKey="true"
        jvmversion="1.7+"/>

    <mkdir dir="dist/SuperNova.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lib"/>
    <copy flatten="true" todir="dist/SuperNova.app/Contents/Resources/Java/lib" includeemptydirs="false">
        <fileset dir="dist/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
```

Now it works perfect.